# missing FROM-clause entry for table "Listing"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is something wrong in this code?

```
SELECT public."Listing" FROM regexp_split_to_table( public."Listing".amenities , ',') AS foo;
```

The column amenities is an array of varchar and I want to split them.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Do you have a column with a (comma  separated) list of table names and you want to do `SELECT * FROM` for each table in the list?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says: `"Listing"`  is not in the FROM list:

```
SELECT foo.*
FROM public."Listing" as l 
   cross join regexp_split_to_table(l.amenities , ',') AS foo;
```

Comment: And how I can pass these values in an existing table column?

Comment: @vkatsou: `l.amenities` **is** table column, isn't it?

Comment: yes it is and I want to store its values to a new column "amenity_name" of table "Amenity" and all varchar type.

Comment: @vkatsou: well, that is a totally different question